# embed flash in the background (hidden on the page)

Tags: javascript, actionscript

I'm trying to make an mp3 player that passes javascript events to a flash file. I'm not very saavy in flash so this may be a simple question.. but how do you make a "movie-less" flash file? Is it possible to just embed an actionscript file? Because that is really all I need to run. Side note: What is the easiest (and fastest) way to pass params to actionscript using javascript?

Thanks,
Matt Mueller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compile actionscript to swf file directly, but you still need to embed in HTML just like a flash file. if you don't want others to see, put that inside `<div style="display:none">...</div>`

Here is the actionscript compilers

http://www.mtasc.org/

http://haxe.org/download

Comment: Thanks! I do have Flash CS4, would it just be easier to write an actionscript file in there and compile it?

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look at Jplayer. This Jquery plug-in does exactly that

http://www.happyworm.com/jquery/jplayer/

Comment: Yah. I'm writing a smaller one that demands better performance. Plus I'm separating the presentation from the Audio logic.